# Двусвязный сортированный список

Tags: алгоритм, список, любой-язык

Сдаётся мне, я какое-то колесо придумываю, но идея в следующем:
Есть стандартный(почти) двусвязный список типа

```
PNode = ^TNode;

TMyObject = class(TObject)
  DateArray: TArray<Byte>;
end;

TNode = Record
  Prev: PNode;
  Next: PNode;
  Data: TMyObject;
  NextSorted; PNode;
end;
```

Ну и какой-то класс-контейнер, который будет хранить все эти узлы
вставка будет в порядке сортированных DateArray.
они все одного размера, могут быть например

```
0.      [0, 1, 3, 4, ......, 1]
1.      [0, 1, 3, 4, ......, 2]
2.      [0, 1, 3, 4, ......, 3]
...
10234.  [1, 1, 3, 4, ......, 1]
10235.  [1, 1, 3, 4, ......, 2]
...
400321. [2, 1, 3, 4, ......, 1]
...
```

NextSorted это дополнительная связь для быстрой навигации, будет использоваться для проверки дубликатов и для поиска при вставке
должен указывать на "след уровень" (если у вставляемого элементра первый элемент массива 0, то NextSorted должен ссылаться на 10234ый, чтобы не проверять все, с сразу прыгнуть к следующему индексу)

Но тут что-то мне не нравится... Например если вставляем элемент с массивом

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, ......, 0]
```

он должен вставиться перед 10234ым и тогда все NextSorted до него нужно переписывать... если их миллион? это будет тормозить вставку. Как тут поправить логику, чтобы и вставка была оптимальная и поиск потом тоже?

Comment: Сделайте `NextSorted` указателем на объект, который содержит указатель `PNode`.

Comment: @Igor, точно! спасибо) А в общем подход правильный или есть более оптимальные решения для тиких целей?

Comment: Для каких целей?

Comment: @MBo, грубо говоря, объекты это будут узлы графа, при вставке нового узла нужно проверить не существует ли он в графе уже, а уникальность определяется тем самым массивом. Потому хотелось бы что-то придумать для быстрого определения существует ли одинаковый массив в одном из узлов и если да, не добавляем новый узел, а строим связь с имеющимся... При большом количестве узлов эта проверка становится слабым местом, хотелось бы менее зависеть от количества

Comment: Возможно RB-tree (или другое сбалансированное дерево) будет лучшим решением.

Comment: @avp, спасибо за наводку, пойду почитаю, потестирую

Comment: @Isaev, OK. Вот тоже может будет чем-то полезно -- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/rbtree.h

Comment: @avp, RB-tree интересная идея, загадкой для меня осталось как в моём случае определять один массив "больше" другого или "меньше" для добавления в дерево?

Comment: Наверное таким же образом, каким вы определяете куда его вставлять в список. Посмотрите, как это делается для [Interval tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/rbtree.txt)

Comment: @avp, это как бы тот же самый вопрос... Это и нужно для того, чтобы определить куда его вставлять

Comment: Глядя на ваш пример списка массивов,  на первый взгляд все просто -- массив по сути это число, где каждый элемент это цифра.

Comment: @avp, спасибо, использовал RB-Tree, прекрасно себя показал в боевых условиях!

Comment: @Isaev, рад, что получилось. Не зря эту структуру данных широко используют в ядре.